# One column used to foreign key to two different tables in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have some entities that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
}

public class RoutedOrder
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  public int RoutingNumber {get; set;}
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
}

public class OrderDetail
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int OrderDetailId {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Order,RoutedOrder")]
  public int OrderId {get; set;}

  public Order Order {get; set;}
  public RoutedOrder RoutedOrder {get; set;}
}
```

The `RoutedOrder` table is an "extension" of the `Order` table.  Not all rows from the `Order` table end up in the `RoutedOrder` table, but those that do get some extra data via extra columns.  But the `OrderId` column is the same value in both tables for the related rows.

Because of that, I don't want two columns in `OrderDetail` to point to each entity.  (They both use `OrderId`.)

When I build the model, `OrderDetail` gets a property added called `RoutedOrderOrderId`.  This causes my database saves to fail (because there is no such column).

**How can I get Entity Framework Core to use `OrderId` as the Foreign Key for both relationships?**

Update:

I want to be able to query `Orders` and get the list of corresponding `OrderDetails` (that have that order's `OrderId` in the `OrderDetail` table).

I also want to be able to do the same with the `RoutedOrder` table. (Query `RoutedOrders` and get the list of corresponding `OrderDetails` (that have that RoutedOrder's `OrderId` in the `OrderDetail` table.)

Additionally, although there the same value exists for `OrderId` in both `Order` and `RoutedOrder`, I don't currently have any Foreign Keys between them.  (I look them up directly, not by linking).  Though if I need to add a FK relationship there to make this work, I can do that.

Comment: It seems there's a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship between Order and RoutedOrder. Why the OrderDetail table? If i'm understanding, you create an Order record and you may or may not create a RoutedOrder record. If and when the RoutedOrder record is created, just use the OrderId value in the Order table for the OrderId value in the RoutedOrder table.

Comment: @GHDevOps - You are right that there is a 1 to (0 or 1) relationship there.  The OrderDetail table holds child records that are a 1 to many relationship from Order/RoutedOrder to OrderDetail.  I want those records to be available on either the Order entity and the RoutedOrder entity.  Sometimes I query the RoutedOrder without getting its full Order record (in reality it is quite large).  So Order has many OrderDetails.  And since RoutedOrder has same Primary Key (of OrderId) it also has many OrderDetails.

Comment: @Vaccano You want the `OrderId` column in `OrderDetail` be the foreign key for the `Order` and `RoutedDetail` table? That means that you can only have `OrderDetail` rows when you have corresponding `Order` and `RoutedOrder` rows. This also means that a single `Order` row can't have any `OrderDetail` rows (because a foreign key in `RoutedOrder` is missing). Is that what you want?

Comment: @Progman - Not quite.  I want to be able to query `Orders` and get the list of corresponding `OrderDetails` (that have that order's `OrderId` in the `OrderDetail` table). 
 I also want to be able to do the same with the `RoutedOrder` table.  (Query `RoutedOrders` and get the list of corresponding `OrderDetails` (that have that RoutedOrder's `OrderId` in the `OrderDetail` table.)

Comment: So `Order` & `RoutedOrder` form a table-per-type heirachy? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit more trial and error, but I got it:

```
public class Order
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
}

public class RoutedOrder
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  public int RoutingNumber {get; set;}

  [InverseProperty("RoutedOrder ")]
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
}

public class OrderDetail
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int OrderDetailId {get; set;}

  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
  public Order Order {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
  public RoutedOrder RoutedOrder {get; set;}
}
```

The changes are:

- Add an `InverseProperty` attribute in RoutedOrder so it knows what property to attach it to.
- Change the `ForeignKey` attribute to be on the navigation properties and point to the Field/Column used to Foreign Key it.

Those two changes got it working fine.